# How should we handle users who never bother to click on answer tick?

Tags: discussion

Some people here in community must exist who never bother to accept answer as answer. How should moderator deal with them? They always gets an answer and disappear. Now more response, never mark answer as answer, but ask next question instead. Moderator should consider these type of users. I think?

Comment: What is the issue? Why is it so important for you that OPs accept/upvote answers?

Comment: Buddy, I Saw this in stackoverflow, so I asked it here.. Nothing important it this

Answer (score 1):

Nobody can mark a question as answered except the asker, not even moderators, and that is by design.

The checkmark means, from the perspective of the asker, "this answer solved my problem or helped me solve my problem." Nobody but the asker can make that judgement. Consequently we do not (and will not) attempt to moderate, scold, encourage, cajole, badger or coerce users into marking questions as answered. It's entirely up to them.

There's nothing bad or incorrect about never accepting an answer on a question.

Comment: But he told me in his next question that previous answer was useful and he forgot to say thanks.. So he thanked me on very next question for the previous answer, but still he didn't mark that

Comment: So? That's not a "problem," in the sense that that's not something that can be moderated. What are you *proposing* we do in these cases?

Comment: At least remind him to do the formalities so next time at least people don't leave your question or don't answer you quickly because of your past reputation

Comment: That's not going to happen; it's very possible and correct that *no* answer helps an asker and thus none *should* be checked. It's also possible the user just never comes back (in which case the reminder is a waste). *You* (or any individual) can suggest to a user that they might consider accepting an answer, but that's not going to be a site policy, and furthermore abusing it (that is, badgering somebody too often to choose an answer) *is not* allowed.

Comment: Actually I saw this at stackoverflow. What can I say...

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the Internet.

Internet is full of people

- that come and go
- that come and stay
- that are intelligent
- that are stupid
- that can read rules and guidelines
- that bother to read rules and guidelines and don't bother abiding by them
- that don't care about the rules and guidelines
- that enjoy using a service by the rules and guidelines
- that act like [boy|girl]-scouts
- that act like bullies

Stack Exchange is on the Internet, and, by default, there is all sorts of people using the site.

Stack Exchange *suggests* to mark the answer as accepted. There is a reward for the OP and for the answer author. You'll find people that will enjoy doing it, and you will find some who don't know or don't care.

And it's ok.

At the end of the day, it's *only* 15 reputation points.

Comment: Currently going worse than that

Comment: @HamzaHasan I'm not sure I understand what you mean here..?

Comment: It was about 15 reputation per day :D

Comment: Fifteen reputation is *trivial*; even if reputation gain is your primary motivator for answering (and I find that unfortunate, if true), a decent answer will generate *far* more reputation over time from votes than it will from acceptance.

Comment: Agreed. And m not here for that. Don't be like that for me :D

Comment: I just saw a [question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/98554/in-unity-why-do-my-animator-states-wait-until-the-end-of-each-animation-to-chan) get updated by Community where the asker *answered their own question* and didn't mark it as accepted.  Given that the user only has 11 rep, I doubt they'll ever return.  It disappoints me that this question will forever rise to the top as a result.